# VisualStudio - Change a checkbox max char length?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, checkbox

I don't see any property to change the default char length of a checkbox label... Can I?

What can I do if not?

Comment: What "char length" do you mean? The Label is not (practically) limited in length. It just does not (afaik) support automatic wrapping, so if you have a very long text, insert linebreaks (Cr + Lf) to get multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following options you can use either of them:

1) You can follow [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/8bc34c7f-79de-4803-98bd-c9b6df412b50) link and append `Environment.NewLine` or `VbCrLf` to `Text` property.

2) Set `AutoSize` property to `false` and resize control to occupy few more line as per your need.